# How to compare DataTrigger Value to Object Reference

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatrigger

Is this even possible?

```
<DataTrigger 
    Binding = {Binding Path=SelectedItem, 
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}
    Value = {Binding}
/>
```

I know that `Value` is not a `DependencyProperty`, but is there any way to have a `DataTrigger` compare object reference equality?

I am trying to style my selected item in my listbox upon it being selected. Currently, my workaround is to have an `IsSelected` property on my model, but that is a pretty ugly hack and requires my `VM` to maintain that `IsSelected` state appropriately.

Comment: How about a `MultiBinding` bound to both Objects that should be compared? In the converter you can use the ReferenceEquals method to check if the references are the same.

Comment: Why not apply a control-template Trigger to `SelectedItem` on the `ListBoxItem`, as in `<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">` ?